API connection failed: ConnectionRefusedError
Error Image
Hi,
i am now to programming and i am trying to connect Interactive brokers with Jupyter Notebook and getting this error. Socket client has been enabled.  I would appreciate some help.
API connection failed: ConnectionRefusedError(22, 'The remote computer refused the network connection', None, 1225, None)

Make sure API port on TWS/IBG is open

post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly .
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
how to ask
